# Combine 2 Arrays In Foreach in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-merge, array-unique

I would like to combine these two foreach statements together. I've seen a few solutions around here, but nothing really works for me.

This is my username list from database.

```
$digits = [1,2,3,4];
$results = $db->table($usernames)
    ->where('memberID', $mID)->limit(10)
    ->getAll();

foreach ($results as $result) {
echo $result->userName;
}
```

I tried this:

```
$combined = array_merge($digits, $results);

foreach (array_unique($dogrularVeSiklar) as $single) : { ?>
    {
        echo $single.'<br>';
        echo $results->userName;
    },
}
```

Comment: Please state your expected result array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show what `$dogrularVeSiklar` is or where you get it, but as an example; combine into `$key => $value` pairs and `foreach` exposing the key and value:

```
$combined = array_combine($digits, $results);

foreach ($combined as $digit => $result) {
        echo $digit . '<br>' . $result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question - I have added some information

Comment: This assumes that both arrays are of the same size ... in which case PDO would achieve the same with its PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR mode.

Answer (score -2):

foreach operates on only one array at a time.

The way your array is structured, you can use [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function to combine them into an array of key-value pairs then foreach that single array